# Scala Lift - AJAX uploader (valums) not accepting IE9 file upload

Tags: ajax, scala, file-upload, upload, lift

I have the following:

```
new qq.FileUploader({

    element: $('#' + domid + ' #upload')[0],
    action: '/api/panel/upload_file',
    debug: true,
    allowedExtensions: [

        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'gif',
        'png',
        'bmp',
        'pdf'

    ],
    params: {

        room : 'a_room',
        module : 'a_module'

    },
    onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {

        this.params.name = fileName;

    },
    onProgress: function(id, fileName, loaded, total) { },
    onComplete : function(id, fileName, data) {

        /* FINISH */

    }

});
```

Which sends the upload request to:

```
case "api" :: "panel" :: "upload_file" :: Nil Post req => {

    var response = true

    req.body match {

        case Full(file) => 

            /* DO SOMETHING */

        case _ => response = false

    }

}
```

This works fine in both Firefox and Chrome, but when uploading with IE9 the file doesnt seem to get past:

```
req.body match {

    case Full(file) =>

}
```

Is there something I'm missing or need to do to get this working properly?

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, req.body will give you an array of bytes, not a file. Lift will automatically detect if you're uploading a file or an arbitrary payload. Its not a good idea to put files into memory, especially if they might be large.

Look into `req.uploadedFiles`, and `req.rawInputStream` with `OnDiskFileParamHolder.apply` - if i recall how vallums uploader works, you have to manually push the input stream into the `FileParamHolder`, from which you can just call .file and then have a direct `java.io.File` instance to work with.